# Looking for specific thinning algorithm

Tags: image-processing, mathematical-morphology

I have a binary image, and for simplicity lets assume it's a simple straight line:

```
00000000000000
00000000000000
00000000000000
11111111110000
00000000000000
00000000000000
00000000000000
```

and I want to extend it for 2px.

For that purpose I applied dilation with two iterations and as expected got this:

```
00000000000000
11111111111100
11111111111100
11111111111100
11111111111100
11111111111100
00000000000000
```

then, my idea was to simply apply thinning and get initial line extended by two pixels. But instead, I got shortened line, probably because of line thickness:

```
00000000000000
10000000000000
10000000000000
11111111100000
10000000000000
10000000000000
00000000000000
```

I then thought to apply dilation with diamond shape structuring footprint instead 3x3 ones(), but result was worse - line was shortened for one more pixel.

For thinning I used [Zhang-Suen algorithm](http://opencv-code.com/quick-tips/implementation-of-thinning-algorithm-in-opencv/) and [Guo-Hall algorithm](http://opencv-code.com/quick-tips/implementation-of-guo-hall-thinning-algorithm/), and I also tried Otsu method exposed by skimage, which yielded similar result.

Can someone tell me about existence of thinning algorithm that can get me where I headed, or maybe different approach?

---

**Update** (to address @marinus comment):

As mentioned, I like to extend the initial line for 2px and get:

```
00000000000000
00000000000000
00000000000000
11111111111100
00000000000000
00000000000000
00000000000000
```

while I can't with my thinning approach, because thinning seems to work this way:

[image: img]

So by just dilating initial line, I can't possibly extend it with thinning.

Comment: I can't figure out what exactly you want. Could you give the output that you are trying to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in the morphological kernel that you are using. In your examples you mention that you simply want to extend the line two pixels in the horizontal direction. The kernel you apply should then match your goal.

For dialtion, every "on" pixel is 'or'd the current pixel and its neighbors with the kernel. The 3x3 kernel will produce 1's all around the current pixel.

```
3x3:

111
111
111
```

If instead you applied a kernel that was 5x1:

```
00000
11111
00000
```

Applying it to your original signal you would get your desired result. If you only want pixels added to the right, do the kernel of 111 with the center of the kernel being on the first pixel.

Comment: Thanks, but I mentioned to consider simple line as an example. My problem are dense contours with gaps, not this literal example. Perhaps I should be looking for other method then dilation with thinning...

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are looking for, However my answer also applies to general cases. If you have a predictable result that you are wanting (i.e. dilating/thinning in based on a certain shape), then the kernel is key. If you're wanting something that adapts based on the components within the image, then yes, I suppose you want a different method.

Comment: Yes, your answer is good in that it explains I should try various kernels, and I'll do that, only that I don't expect it to work with mentioned thinning algorithms and I was more looking for that kind of advice. Problem is that I have dense contours with gaps, which can be closed with triangulation, but it's so complicated because result is never correct, so I'm trying various other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Zhang-Suen thinning algorithm in javascript.js

```
for(x=0;x<5;x++){
for(n=0;n<2;n++){
for(i=0;i<len;){
p1=pp[i];p2=pp[i-width];p3=pp[i-width+1];
p8=pp[i-1];p9=pp[i-width-1];p4=pp[i+1];
p7=pp[i+width-1];p6=pp[i+width];p5=pp[i+width+1];
/* pixels position  
9   2   3
8   1   4   
7   6   5


*/
zn=0;
b=p2+p3+p4+p5+p6+p7+p8+p9;
if(p2<p3){zn++;}
if(p3<p4){zn++;}
if(p4<p5){zn++;}
if(p5<p6){zn++;}
if(p6<p7){zn++;}
if(p7<p8){zn++;}
if(p8<p9){zn++;}
if(p9<p2){zn++;}
if(b>=2&&b<=6&&zn==1&&p2*p4*p6==0&&p4*p6*p8==0&&n==0){id.push(i);}
if(b>=2&&b<=6&&zn==1&&p2*p4*p8==0&&p2*p6*p8==0&&n==1){id.push(i);}
i++;}
for(i=0;i<id.length;i++){pp[id[i]]=0;}id=[];
}}
```

result :// https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-rtDafT3tJ-Q/UqT6thazqJI/AAAAAAAABPE/b2dc7PQNZ24/w973-h220-no/Screenshot+from+2013-12-09+00%253A58%253A36.png

REFERENCES :

jsAscii - ASCII art from images with Javascript and Canvas convert image to dots http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/03/jsascii.html